# get images from directory using aws s3 in php

Tags: php, aws-sdk

I have get images from my bucket with subfolder in bucket. But i have not get proper result using following code.

```
<?php 
require('app/start.php');
require('app/database.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [
    'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
    'Prefix' => 'sitefiles/',
    'Delimiter' => '/'
]);
echo '<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Listings</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    <tbody>';
        foreach($objects as $object) {
                echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$object['Key'].'</td> 
            </tr>';
        }

    echo '</tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>';
?>
```

How can get result from that code

I get following result:

result

```
sitefiles/
sitefiles/lion-wild-africa-african.jpg
```

but want second record from that result

Comment: `sitefiles` have another nested folder named `sitefiles`?

Comment: no only one `sitefiles` folder in my bucket

Comment: Go for the for loop and start your index from 1

Comment: in that i have use following error `aws-sdk` is that: `Object of class Aws\S3\Iterator\ListObjectsIterator could not be converted to int`

Comment: show your code. what you are doing.